# How to exclude a column when using getAllColumns property in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have a function that counts and hides the number of columns that does not fit the screen. I want to exclude a column when resizing and hiding the columns. Here is what I have.

```
let ctrOfColumns = this.gridOptionsValue.columnApi.getAllColumns();
```

this returns the columns that i have. I want to exclude a specific column which has a colId of 'toBeExcludedId' so that It won't be included in the hiding of columns algo.

Here is my algo in hiding of the columns

```
let gridWidthOfMyTable = $('#idOfMyGrid').outerWidth();
let columnsToBeShown = [];
let columnsToBeHidden = [];
let totalWidthOfColumn = 0;

for(let x = 0 ; x < ctrOfColumns.length; x ++){
 const singleColumn = ctrOfColumns[x];
        totalWidthOfColumn += singleColumn.getMinWidth();
        if (totalWidthOfColumn > gridWidthOfMyTable) {
            columnsToBeHidden.push(singleColumn);
        } else {
            columnsToBeShown.push(singleColumn);
        }
}
this.gridOptionsValue.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(columnsToBeShown, true);
this.gridOptionsValue.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(columnsToBeHidden, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to loop through all the values in your array. You can just use chaining and apply a filter directly to getAllColumns(), like this:

```
let ctrOfColumns = this.gridOptionsValue
 .columnApi
 .getAllColumns()
 .filter((column) => column.colId !== 'toBeExcludedId');
```